# Proving a sequence to be a cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Define a sequence just as shown below:
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin⁡ k}{k^2 }$$
It is required to show that the above sequence will be a Cauchy sequence.

I am sharing what I have tried to solve this problem:

As per the definition of Cauchy sequence I have considered two natural numbers $m$ and $n$
where $m>n$ now I considered the following expression:
$$|x_m-x_n |=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{\sin ⁡k}{k^2} \right|  $$
I tried to figure out an expression of n which will be an upper bound for the RHS of the just above equation I have considered.

I am writing the RHS of my just above equation whose upper bound I need to figure out as ‘$r’$.

I came up with the following expression:
$$r\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{n}$$
But,
$\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-\dfrac{1}{n}$ doesn’t converges to $0$ that’s where I am having the problem, if I could get an upper bound for my RHS with such an expression of n which converges to 0 then the problem would get solved.

I don’t know whether my approach will be of any help of solving the problem.
Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Your upper bound should be $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n >m$ we have $-\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac 1 {k^{2}} \leq x_n-x_m \leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac 1 {k^{2}}$. Use the fact that the series $\sum \frac 1 {k^{2}}$ is convergent.